# How to access ssh key file in a Teamcity right in a job without SSH upload

Tags: teamcity

I have a job that ssh into other servers and deploys some configuration with scp, but I can not find any  way to access ssh key file used in my project configuration in TeamCity in order to execute shell command  in my job -  "ssh -I ~/.ssh/password", because TeamCity runs only in job directory. Therefore, I want to ask is there any way to access this SSH private key file that I mentioned in a project settings.

Just to say, I cannot use SSH-EXEC and SSH-UPLOAD as I have Shell script that ssh into many servers one by one reading from a file, therefore it would not be useful to have for each job one separate SSH exec job step in TeamCity project, so I have to somehow access the file without using standard SSH-EXEC and SSH-UPLOAD in a TeamCity

What have I tried?
I only had one idea - somehow to access SSH key that is located outside working directory by a path (I found this in documentation):

```
<TeamCity Data Directory>/config/projects/<project>/pluginData/ssh_keys
```

Problem with this, is that I cannot just cd into given path, as job does not want to go outside my working directory where job is executed by TeamCity. Therefore I could not access given directory where ssh_keys for my project is located.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Find out solution to use build feature SSH, that way you can execute SSH-key right with command line in job